# Exception stacktrace and cause not mapped to the custom global exception handling in Micronaut 2.5.8

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

Trying to handle the global exception handling in Micronaut, but the exception stack trace and cause are not thrown to the ExceptionHandler.

```
public class GlobalException extends RuntimeException{
    public GlobalException(Throwable throwable){}
}



@Produces
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = {GlobalException.class, ExceptionHandler.class})
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<GlobalException, HttpResponse> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public HttpResponse handle(HttpRequest request, GlobalException exception) {
        LOG.error(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        LOG.error(exception.getCause().getCause().getMessage());
        Arrays.stream(exception.getStackTrace()).forEach(item ->  LOG.error(item.toString()));
        return HttpResponse.serverError(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public Maybe<FindProductCommand> get(ProductSearchCriteriaCommand searchCriteria) {
        LOG.info("Controller --> Finding all the products");
        return iProductManager.find(searchCriteria)
                .onErrorResumeNext(error ->  { return Maybe.error(new GlobalException(error));});
    }
```

The actual error are not mapped in GlobalExceptionHandler. `exception.getLocalizedMessage()` is null and `LOG.error(exception.getCause().getCause().getMessage())` is throwing null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GlobalException`'s constructor has a `Throwable` parameter and it's swallowing it (not doing anything with it). `RuntimeException` also has a single argument constructor that takes a `Throwable`, so `GlobalException(Throwable throwable)` is effectively hiding `RuntimeException(Throwable throwable)`.

Thus when your controller gets to:

```
return Maybe.error(new GlobalException(error));
```

1. `error` is being swallowed
2. `exception.getLocalizedMessage()` returns `null` since the `RuntimeException(Throwable throwable)` constructor can't propogate `throwable` to `Exception(Throwable throwable)` (`RuntimeException` extends `Exception`) and `GlobalException` doesn't override `Exception#getLocalizedMessage()`
3. `LOG.error(exception.getCause().getCause().getMessage())` is throwing
   a `NullPointerException` because `exception.getCause()` is returning `null` due to `error` being swallowed (from list item `1`)

In conclusion, either don't hide `RuntimeException(Throwable throwable)` in `GlobalException`, via:

```
public class GlobalException extends RuntimeException {}
```

Or just invoke `RuntimeException(Throwable throwable)` from `GlobalException(Throwable throwable)`, via:

```
public class GlobalException extends RuntimeException {
     public GlobalException(Throwable throwable) {
         super(throwable);
     }
}
```